# Routing in Ajax petition in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I have the following in my view:

```
$('#anID tr').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/tickets/extended_info',
            dataType: 'script',
            data: { id: $(this).find('td:first').html() }
        });
    });
```

and this in my tickets controller:

```
def extended_info(id)
    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + id.to_s
  end
```

But I always get 404 not found from the ajax request.

I think I'm missing something in my routes file... I tried several things, but nothing.

Any ideas?

**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> RESOLVED <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**

I had to add:

```
map.extendedInfo '/extended_info/:id', :controller => 'tickets', :action => 'extended_info'
```

to my routes file.

Also, I was using "GET" in my ajax call in my JavaScript ... I changed to POST and now it's working =)

Answer (score 0):

Really seems like routing trouble. Do you have appropriate row for /tickets/extended_info path in your routes.rb? If so, can you post it here?

I suppose something like this

```
get "/ticket/extended_info", :to => "tickets_controller#extended_info"
```

in routes.rb and your action on controller should be just

```
def extended_info
  puts params[:id].inspect
end
```